# why google maps example are not displayed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could you please tell me why google maps example  are not displayed ?
Here is my code

https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#introduction
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is being downvoted because you haven't included any code you've attempted to solve your problem. You should read the help section on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

They did some changes to the map api a while back, think you have to pay to use it now

> One of the main reasons Google Maps stopped working on your site may
>   be the changes in Google policies concerning the work of Google Maps,
>   announced on 16 July. More specifically, from now on to display Google
>   Maps on your website you need to get a Google Maps API key. This is a
>   kind of token, connecting your widget and Google Maps API [Ref](https://elfsight.com/blog/2018/06/google-maps-not-working-website/)

Cant find a date for the link you provided but i guesse it was posted before 16 July

[image]